# php mail() to multiple recipients - dont share email adresses

Tags: php, email

im sending a batch email to multiple recipients using:

```
mail(implode(',', $emails), $subject, $content, $headers);
```

however, each person can see the list of who the email was sent to. I want to keep this private, and also so the email appears more personal.

is there a way to do this without sending a mail() to each email, as I'm guessing this will take a long time to run?

Comment: Why don't add the email IDs in `bcc` field in your email header?

Comment: FYI: Using BCC, email address(es) will still show up in full headers. Use a DB.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a simple BCC address. Everyone in the same mail but not able to see each others email address.

Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and find the BCC.

this is the piece you need:

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";
$headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `bcc` header to to your message

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: email' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```